# How to programmatically share a Google Sheet with an email, via Python API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have list of Google Sheets that I would like to modify, such that a specific email is granted an `Editor` access. However, instead of doing this manually, I would like to be able to do it programmatically, using the Google Python client.

I am aware I can potentially use the Drive API,

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',      
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]

drive_client = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

however, I am still not sure how to go about granting `Editor` or `Viewer` permissions to an entity/email, for a specific Google Sheet (without possibly affecting existing permission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]

permission = {
  'type': 'user',
  'role': 'writer',
  'emailAddress': 'example@example.com',
}

file_id = 'abc-12345'

creds, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)

try:
    request = service.permissions().create(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=permission,
    )
    response = request.execute()
except HttpError as error:
    # handle exception
    print(f'Error was: {error}')
```

PS: You may also have to ensure you have authenticated gcloud with the required scopes/permissions:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam.test
```

---

Source:
[How to Change Google Sheet permissions with Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/google-sheet-permissions-python-fee1ff80363)